# How to retrieve Data from a Hibernate hbm file

Tags: java, hibernate

how can i retrieve data in table from hibernate (hbm) file?

Is there any process or method for this??

or we can manually done it

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a `someTable.hbm.xml`, you will also have a `hibernate.cfg.xml`, that contains the information needed to access the database anyway you like. Hibernate knows how to provide you with data based on these files. Just open a Session or HQL and enjoy. This is the standard method.
If this is not what you wan, you can do anything else you like, even use JDBC based on the information you gathered from `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what data you want to retrieve from HBM file? Class definitions? Mappings?

One simple way is to do XML parsing of the same using SAX/DOM or JAXB, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear, I think you want to know how to retrieve data from the database tables using hibernate.?
If thats so, please go through the following link. Read it through so that you get a basic idea on how to work with hibernate.
http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/index.shtml

Answer (score 0):

And if it was the Hibernate meta-data you were after, you can get to some of it through a Configuration instance.